# Database error -database details are not defined

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, server, web-hosting

How can I solve this error to make a drupal website live

> messagePDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /home/arvod374/public_html/includes/lock.inc).

As I checked inside the file: /home/arvod374/public_html/sites/default/settings.php the database details are not defined and you will need to proceed and define them and then check your website once again. but how?

error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Add  code sample , it will helps lot to give a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using Drupal 7.

In your `settings.php` you should find a section entitled **Database settings**. It should start somewhere near line 55. It contains examples of how to set up database configuration. After this section, add following code:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'YOUR_DB_NAME',
      'username' => 'YOUR_DB_USER',
      'password' => 'YOUR_DB_PASSWORD',
      'host' => 'YOUR_DB_HOST',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Fill placeholders `YOUR_DB_NAME` etc. with your actual data. (Of course, database and database user should be already set up.) If your MySQL server runs the same physical server as your site, then `YOUR_DB_HOST` should be `localhost` (otherwise IP address of MySQL server).

Answer (score 0):

In your source code , you might has PDO configurations as follows ,
`$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);`. You need to specify username, password, host